# What does a resistor pointing to the middle of another resistor symbolize?

Tags: resistors, potentiometer

[image: Picture of resistors]

As the picture shows, is this a potentiometer, or is it supposed to be two resistors?

Answer (score 4):

The picture shows two potentiometers, each of value 100k.  The wiper of each potentiometer is connected to a fixed resistor, one of 100k and one of 1M.  Each fixed resistor is connected to what looks like a thermistor (the circled things marked 10k.)

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuZrWC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuits.*

- R1 allows selection of a bias voltage between 0 and -12 V.
- R2 limits the current from the bias to the next stage of the circuit.
- Note that your coarse pot wiper resistor is 100 kΩ and the fine is 1 MΩ. If they both feed into the same circuit the fine pot adjustment will be ten times more sensitive than the coarse pot because the 1 MΩ resistor reduces its effect to one tenth that of the coarse pot.